# merging two tables but some rows are missing

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am trying to join two tables in R but I don't get the expected result.
Here are two example data.tables

```
dt1 <- data.table(s = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  d = c(1,2,3,1,2),
                  c = c(8,8,8,9,9),
                  v = c(6,6,6,6,6))

dt2 <- data.table(s = c(1,1,1),
                  d = c(1,2,3))
```

I am trying to get this result

```
dt3 <- data.table(s = c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  d = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  c = c(8,8,8,9,9,9),
                  v = c(6,6,6,6,6,NA))
```

but using

```
dt4 <- data.table::merge.data.table(dt2, dt1, by = c("s", "d"), all = TRUE)
```

but dt4 is missing the last entry `6: 1 3 9 NA`

any suggstion?

Comment: `all` values are represented. 1/1, 1/2 and 1/3 of the keys in `dt2`. The 1/3 in `dt2` joined to row 3 of `dt1`. You can see what-joins-to-what if you add row numbers beforehand `dt1[, rn1 := .I]; dt2[, rn2 := .I]; merge(dt2, dt1, by=c("s","d"), all=TRUE)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to get your desired result without substantially changing `dt2` - it seems you need to also join on the `c` column, e.g.: `merge(dt1, data.table(s = c(1,1,1,1,1,1), d=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), c=c(8,8,8,9,9,9)), by=c("s","d","c"), all=TRUE)`

Comment: What is the logic behind your desired result?

Comment: @s_baldur You could think of the following example. "s" subjects in a trial, "d" are the days of the trials subject "s" has attended, "c" is the treatment given to subject "s" on day "d" , and "v" is the outcome of the treatment. For further processing I need "v" to have v = 0 when "s" on "day "d" has not received the treatment "c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a two-step solution---which can, of course, be combined into one step.

Step #1:

```
dt4 <- unique(dt1[,.(s, c)])[dt2, on = .(s), all = TRUE]
```

and Step #2:

```
dt5 <- dt1[dt4, on = .(s, d, c)][order(s,c,d)]
```

resulting in

```
> dt5
   s d c  v
1: 1 1 8  6
2: 1 2 8  6
3: 1 3 8  6
4: 1 1 9  6
5: 1 2 9  6
6: 1 3 9 NA
```